# How to make dynamic user controls play nice with the designer

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, windows-forms-designer

I have a dynamic user control that instantiates various bars and labels dynamically based on the number of members in a object group. This functionality works out very well, but the issue is that I am not the only developer on this project. I am new to the team and the "senior" members want all of the components to work in the designer. Since the components of the user control are generated at run time I am not sure how to go about making some/any of them show up in design view. Is this even an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, because there is no markup for the designer to show. I find it hard to believe that they would expect dynamically created controls to show in the designer.

**EDIT**

Thinking about it some more, why don't you just add a few hard-coded instances of the control in the markup, with the ability to add/remove. That way, the control is displayed in the designer, but you can still add/remove instances. That would probably be the best compromise in this case.

Comment: Truth be told they did not want any dynamic controls, but rather then create 5-7 of the same control each having a different number of bars and labels (as dictated by object group). I made a one size fits all control that is dynamic.

Comment: They wanted a hard-coded number of controls? What if you need more instances of the control? That doesn't sound right... if there's a case for making the control dynamic, you shouldn't have to compromise your design to satisfy the designer. That's just putting unnecessary limitations on the design.

Comment: I agree, but by pleas fall on deaf ears, the fact remains that they are addicted to seeing every element of the form in the designer. So much so that our project is comprised of hundreds of these duplicate controls. So yes this means that they would rather have a hard coded number of controls so they have a visual. I was hoping there was a way to get around the stupidity and make the designer show some default value for my dynamic control to appease the masters, while coding this thing properly.

Comment: @Siegeon: See my edited answer. That's the only way I can think of to meet their wishes without imposing limitations on the design. That really is a cringe-worthy approach though... just saying ;)

Comment: @Siegeon: I recall you're mentioning that you're new to this position, but when developers put their preferences ahead of the user experience, it's the users who end up paying the cost for it. If you ever do bring it up, I would approach it from that angle, in defense of those who will be using the system.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, so basically place the previous hard coded version of the control in the designer, and when then program starts just replace with my control; not a bad approach at all. As you mentioned I am new here, but the general attitude with some of these things is "This is the way it is done." I will use your advice and respond in kind the next time our group meets. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give both the possibility of defining the number of dynamic controls at design time, and at run time?

1. In your custom control class, you can define a property that specifies the number of controls. Implement adding/removing controls in the set{} method of this property.
2. Make your property a "designer property". See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a19191fh.aspx

Keep in mind that the designer actually creates an instance of your class. Also, when a user changes your "property" in the designer, the set{} method is invoked.

I hope this helps

Comment: Oh that looks very cool, I have never attempted something like that, but it seems to be the very thing I need. I will see if I can work it out. Thank you.